# Power BI - DOUBLE data type consuming enormously large space

Tags: powerbi, double

I am using a Power BI model on top of Snowflake. I have some columns in snowflake which are like NUMBER(38,0). When these columns are imported in Power BI, those are coming as DOUBLE.

The problem is, the space consumed by the double data type within Power BI is way more than the space consumed by NUMBER data type in Snowflake. I mean the object size is ~30% more in Power BI than Snowflake.

This is causing the Power BI data-set size to be enormously large.

If I try to change the data type in Power BI as whole number, it is saying object has to be in "IMPORT" mode. In my case the object is in "DUAL" mode.

Is there any other way, can we handle this data type and/or size growth.

Comment: Do you need that level of precision?

Comment: How are you measuring the size in Power BI?

Comment: I tried using BIGINT in Snowflake, but it converted to NUMBER(38,0) and the same is using DOUBLE in Power BI